# Can I use the na_kalman function in R (imputeTS) to replace missing data in a bivariate time series if the function is applied to only one series?

Tags: time-series, data-imputation

I am doing a bivariate time series analysis. There is missing data in one of the series (approximately 5% of the data ist missing). Is it appropriate to use the na_kalman function i R (package: imputeTS) for univariate  time series imputation for the series with the missing values or do I have to apply a method for multivariate time series imputation?

Comment: What is the end goal here? Are you going to fit a joint model to your series afterwards and if so, what kind? Are the series strongly related, in a way that you might expect that you can use the fully available series to get better estimates of the missing values of the other series?

Comment: The goal is to fit a second-order vector autoregressive model to the series and examine the causal effect of one series to the other one. The series are moderately related.          @Chris Haug

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily *inappropriate* to use a univariate model (as is done by `imputeTS::na_kalman`) for this, although it may not be *optimal*, for two reasons:

1. Estimates of missing observations are not data, and this matters quite a bit more when observations are not independent. This implies that, if you then fit another multivariate model based on these estimates as if they were actually observed, and the first step univariate dynamics are not similar enough to the dynamics from the second step, you could have issues with fitting the multivariate model because it will have inconsistent dynamics (and prediction intervals will also be wrong, etc). For that reason, it is often recommended that this be done in one step in a single, coherent multivariate model.
2. A multivariate model can, if a relationship between the series exists, be exploited to obtain much better estimates of the missing values (conditioned on the other series that aren't missing).

If a VAR model is appropriate for the data, then the best course of action is probably to fit the VAR model directly, without imputing first (you can impute at the end if you actually need to). You can do this fairly easily because a VAR model is a linear Gaussian state space model, so that the Kalman filter can be used to fit the model with an arbitrary pattern of missingness. It is a straightforward extension of what `imputeTS::na_kalman` is doing, although I'm not aware of whether that package or another has an existing implementation.